# Estimating angle between two random vectors

Tags: numerical-integration, random

I'm interested in angles between random vectors on unit ball. Expected value of cosine is 0 by symmetry, so, expectation of cosine squared is the interesting bit.

The following `NExpectation` takes several minutes and gives error margins that are 50% of the answer ...is this a fundamentally hard problem for numerical integration, or are there tricks to make it easier?

```
x := {x1, x2, x3, x4};
y := {y1, y2, y3, y4};
normal := MultinormalDistribution[{0, 0, 0, 0}, IdentityMatrix[4]];
vars := {x \[Distributed] normal, 
  y \[Distributed] 
   normal};
NExpectation[(x.y/(Norm[x] Norm[y]))^2, vars]
```

Get

```
NIntegrate::slwcon: Numerical integration converging too slowly; suspect one of the following: singularity, value of the integration is 0, highly oscillatory integrand, or WorkingPrecision too small.
```

PS, the real motivation is to verify that the following formula (obtained through guessing) works for vectors sampled from more general distribution --

```
val1[a_, b_, c_, 
  d_] := (a + b + c + d)/(Sqrt[a] + Sqrt[b] + Sqrt[c] + Sqrt[d])^2
val2[a_, b_, c_, d_] := Block[{},
  x := {x1, x2, x3, x4};
  y := {y1, y2, y3, y4};
  normal := 
   MultinormalDistribution[{0, 0, 0, 
     0}, {{a, 0, 0, 0}, {0, b, 0, 0}, {0, 0, c, 0}, {0, 0, 0, d}}];
  vars := {x \[Distributed] normal, y \[Distributed] normal};
  NExpectation[(x.y/(Norm[x] Norm[y]))^2, vars]]
val1[0.5, 1.5, 2.5, 3.5] - val2[0.5, 1.5, 2.5, 3.5]
```

Comment: I haven't checked in detail, but almost certainly all the delayed assignments are horribly slowing down your function.

Comment: Are you specifically interested in the answer in 4D?

Comment: I think if I can show it for 4D with high numeric confidence, I'll have good confidence this formula works for arbitrary dimensions

Comment: Have you already tried transforming the integral in Carl's answer to [hyperspherical coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3-sphere#Hyperspherical_coordinates)?

Answer (score 5):

We can peek at the integral *Mathematica* is performing under the hood:

```
TracePrint[
    NExpectation[(x.y/(Norm[x] Norm[y]))^2, vars], 
    _NIntegrate,
    TraceAction->((Print[InputForm@#];Abort[])&)
]
```

> `` HoldForm[NIntegrate[(E^((-x1^2 - x2^2 - x3^2 - x4^2)/2 + (-y1^2 - y2^2 - y3^2 - y4^2)/2)*(x1*y1 + x2*y2 + x3*y3 + x4*y4)^2)/(16*Pi^4*(Abs[x1]^2 + Abs[x2]^2 + Abs[x3]^2 + Abs[x4]^2)*(Abs[y1]^2 + Abs[y2]^2 + Abs[y3]^2 + Abs[y4]^2)), {x1, -Infinity, Infinity}, {x2, -Infinity, Infinity}, {x3, -Infinity, Infinity}, {x4, -Infinity, Infinity}, {y1, -Infinity, Infinity}, {y2, -Infinity, Infinity}, {y3, -Infinity, Infinity}, {y4, -Infinity, Infinity}, AccuracyGoal -> Statistics`NExpectationDump`$NExpectationAccuracyGoal, Compiled -> Statistics`NExpectationDump`$NExpectationCompiled, PrecisionGoal -> Statistics`NExpectationDump`$NExpectationPrecisionGoal, WorkingPrecision -> Statistics`NExpectationDump`$NExpectationWorkingPrecision, MinRecursion -> Statistics`NExpectationDump`minrec$24078, Sequence[]]] ``
>
> $Aborted

As you can see, it is an 8-dimensional integral, so I'm not surprised that *Mathematica* is having difficulties. Perhaps you can work with this integral directly instead, and play with [`Method`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Method.html) options, or alternate parametrizations?